# asp.net detect any tablet device with user agent string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-agent, tablet

Is it possible to detect if a request is coming from a tablet device (iPad, Android, etc.) with server side code?

EDIT:  I need to know if it's an android tablet instead of an android phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Detecting mobile device user agents in ASP.NET (Android)](http://forums.asp.net/t/1595912.aspx/1):

```
 //for Mobile device 
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) 
    { 

        string userAgent = Request.UserAgent; 
        if (userAgent.Contains("BlackBerry") 
          || (userAgent.Contains("iPhone") || (userAgent.Contains("Android")))) 
        { 
            //add css ref to header from code behind 
            HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink(); 
            css.Href = ResolveClientUrl("~/mobile.css"); 
            css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";  
            css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";  
            css.Attributes["media"] = "all";  
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(css); 
        }       
    }
```

Comment: This looks correct, but I need a way to determine the difference between android phone and android tablets.

Comment: I'm using userAgent.Contains("Android") && !userAgent.Contains("mobile") to differentiate between tablet and phone on the android.

Comment: Kindle fire passes mobile in user agent - http://www.labnol.org/software/kindle-user-agent-string/20378/